# How to get URL for youtube api from fragment and set to YoutubeFragment

Tags: android

Here what I am trying is to get Video URL from fragment where I am calling `youtubeFragmentActivity` like this.In `Tab2Frag` Fragment. I am calling `youtubeFragmentActivity`.

```
public class Tab2Frag extends Fragment {

    public static String PRO_ID;
    public static String youtube_url1;

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        new Show_data().execute();
        new Adds1().execute();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("youtube_details", youtube_url1);
        System.out.println("@@2@@@"+youtube_url1);
        YouTubeFragmentActivity youTubeFragmentActivity=new YouTubeFragmentActivity();
        youTubeFragmentActivity.setArguments(data);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main, youTubeFragmentActivity).commit();


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mainActivity=(MainActivity)activity;
    }


    class Show_data extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ProgressDialog mDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
             PRO_ID = bundle.getString("PRODUCT_ID");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=get_detail&id="+PRO_ID);
            try{
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(data);  
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonobject.getString("detail"));
                for(int j=0; j<jsonarray.length();j++){
                    JSONObject itemobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                    //SHOW SEARCH RESULT
                    Get_detailsBeams get_detailsBeams = new Get_detailsBeams(); 

                    get_detailsBeams.setId(itemobj.getString("ID"));
                    get_detailsBeams.setYoutube(itemobj.getString("youtube_detail"));
                    get_detailsBeams.setTerms_condition(itemobj.getString("terms_condition"));


                    Log.v("Details", itemobj.toString());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            final String youtube_url;
                try {


                            youtube_url = jobj.opt("youtube_detail").toString();
                            System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url);
                            youtube_url1=youtube_url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","");
                            System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()){
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
                }

        }
    }
```

My **YouTubeFragmentActivity**

```
public class YouTubeFragmentActivity extends Fragment {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static String YOU_TUBE;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_you_tube_api, container, false);
            Bundle extras = getArguments();
            YOU_TUBE = extras.getString("youtube_details");
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+YOU_TUBE+"@@@@@@@2");
            YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("DEVELOPER_KEY", new OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    if (!b) {
                        YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        YPlayer.loadVideo(YOU_TUBE);
                        YPlayer.play();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                    // YouTube error
                    String errorMessage = error.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
                }
            });
         return rootView;
        }


}
```

Log:

```
 ####Ashu in preExecute
 @@2@@@Vij0z6NS5BE
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@Vij0z6NS5BE@@@@@@@2
 @@@@3@https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vij0z6NS5BE
 @@@@3@Vij0z6NS5BE
 VAR@@@@50.86947
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quitely old topic, however, to let everyone else know the problem i the future, let check this

```
SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();
```

Just tack rId.getVideoId() onto youtube.com/watch?v= and you have the url.

```
String url = "youtube.com/watch?v=" + rId.getVideoId();
```

When you get your own `String url` you pass your data throught bundle like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(YOUR_TAG, YOUR_STRING_URL);
 YourFragment mYourFragment = new YourFragment();
 mYourFragment.setArguments(bundle);

 //Do your fragment transaction
```